# Update rate limits at runtime usando WebApiThrottle não está funcionando

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma WebApi em ASP.NET MVC e eu preciso controlar o limite de acesso, além disso, preciso alterar os valores dos limites em tempo de execução. Eu implementei como este exemplo no site [WebApiThrottle](https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle) (seção **Update rate limits at runtime**)

Esse é o código no meu WebApiConfig:

```
//trace provider
var traceWriter = new SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter()
{
    IsVerbose = true
};
config.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), traceWriter);
config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

//Web API throttling handler
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ThrottlingHandler(
    policy: new ThrottlePolicy(perMinute: 3, perHour: 30, perDay: 35, perWeek: 3000)
    {
        //scope to IPs
        IpThrottling = true,
        //scope to clients
        ClientThrottling = true,
        ClientRules = new Dictionary<string, RateLimits>
        {
            { "client-key-1", new RateLimits { PerMinute = 1, PerHour = 60 } }
        },

        //scope to endpoints
        EndpointThrottling = true
    },

    //replace with PolicyMemoryCacheRepository for Owin self-host
    policyRepository: new PolicyCacheRepository(),

    //replace with MemoryCacheRepository for Owin self-host
    repository: new CacheRepository(),

    logger: new TracingThrottleLogger(traceWriter)));
```

Estou definindo três requisições por minuto como padrão e uma requisições por minuto para o cliente com a chave "client-key-1". Mas quando eu testo usando o PostMan (estou passando o token de Autorização com o valor client-key-1), notei que apenas a configuração padrão está sendo usada porque somente após três pedidos recebi a mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E, mesmo que eu atualize o limite de taxa, usando a função:

```
public void UpdateRateLimits()
{
    //init policy repo
    var policyRepository = new PolicyCacheRepository();

    //get policy object from cache
    var policy = policyRepository.FirstOrDefault(ThrottleManager.GetPolicyKey());

    //update client rate limits
    policy.ClientRules["client-key-1"] =
        new RateLimits { PerMinute = 20 };

    //apply policy updates
    ThrottleManager.UpdatePolicy(policy, policyRepository);

}
```

A mensagem ""API calls quota exceeded! maximum admitted 3 per Minute." continua a aparecer.

Alguém já teve esse problema?